# How to forge Referer Header in GET method triggered on HTML

Tags: http, csrf, html, referer

I'm looking through the CSRF vulnerabilities of the DVWA. I run into the medium level which uses this piece of code to validate if the `referer` header equals the server name:

`if( eregi( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ], $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] ) )`.

If so, my query will be accepted and triggered on a database changing login info. I'm doing this through a malicious [webpage](https://pastebin.com/WvSzeR4A).

So far I was able to see what the [Referer name is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLaLy.jpg) on a response header from the server. From my understanding,that php function is asking the following:

**Is the value of $_SERVER[‘SERVER_NAME’] present in $_SERVER[‘HTTP_REFERER’]?**

So, my first thought was, trying to manipulate the request URL string and embed the referer header on it. (no results) I'm assuming that the *if statement* is just looking for a pattern. The thing is that I don't know how to pass it and quiet honestly I don't understand if my GET request is present in `$_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ]` or in  `$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ]`. From my investigation I think the referer header cannot be changed in a simple html img tag. So my last question would be: **Am I able to forge the string of img tag (HTTP request GET) in a way that the statement evaluates to true? If not, how can I do that in a scenario where a victim always uses this malicious webpage unconsciously?**

Comment: Is there an open redirect anywhere? Could send the victim through that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really straightforward!

**Tip:**

> The check verifies if the requesting URL contains the string `localhost`, but not if it *starts* with it. So how do you get the string `localhost` in the referrer (at any place)?

**Solution:**

> You need to send the request from a page that contains the target hostname in its URL.
>
> So if your DVWA instance is hosted on `localhost`, you need to embed that string in the URL. Just send the CSRF request from `http://evilhost/?localhost`. This will produce a referrer header like this:
>
> ```
> Referer: http://evilhost/?localhost
> ```
>
> That's enough to pass the check.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Do you mean something like this `http://localhost:82/vulnerabilities/csrf/?password_new=123&password_conf=123&Change=Change/?localhost` ?

Comment: @fish202 No, the string needs to in the URL of the *requesting* site.  What's the URL of the site you send the request from?

Comment: Well @Arminius... it's just a path to an html file, something like `file:///home/auser/csrf.html`. You can see that it's a local file on my machine. That's why I'm confused with your answer. I'm pretty sure that this is simple but I'm not getting that.

Comment: @fish202 Local files never send referrers. You need to launch it from a webserver instead. Then, you'd open it with an URL like `http://yourevilserver/csrf.html?localhost`.

Comment: ok, I see...I had the feeling that something was missing. I'll give it a try asap and then I'll get back to you. thx

Comment: @fish202 Did you have any success?

Comment: kind of...Now I can see that **referer** [is sent](https://imgur.com/a/UJuiX) on HTTP request. But query status returns failed. Not sure why... I have dvwa running in a docker container listening on localhost:81 and for this purpose I ran apache2 on localhost:80 and then I made the request like this: `localhost:80/csrf.html?localhost` . Is this approach correct?

Comment: Nevermind, I requesting it on a wrong port. Now it's working @Arminius.
Thank you for the precious help!